# Why can't we eliminate $t$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading Lang's *Introduction to Linear Algebra*. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAjt2.jpg) he says that it's not possible to eliminate $t$ in more dimensions. My problem is: Thinking about the method he gave in the first page, it seems he's doing as the following:

$$(x,y)=(a,b)+t(c,d) \\ (x,y)=(a+tc,b+td) \\ x=a+tc \quad  y=b+td \\ \frac{(x-a)}{c}=t=\frac{(y-b)}{d}\\ (x-a)d-(y-b)c=0$$

But I've tried to do something and It seems it's actually possible to do the same in $5$ dimensions for example:

$\quad \quad \quad \quad  \quad \quad  \quad \quad  \quad \quad \quad $ [image]

$\quad \quad \quad \quad  \quad \quad  \quad \quad  \quad \quad \quad $[image]

$\quad \quad \quad \quad  \quad \quad  \quad \quad  \quad \quad \quad $[image]

$\quad \quad \quad$[image]

Comment: Something familar to line equation in 3d or more.

Comment: Getting your parametric equation into that last form is always possible.  **BUT** only in $2$D can you get just $1$ equation which describes a line.  That is, try to solve $x_5 = f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ or $a_1(x_1 - b_1) + a_2(x_2 - b_2) + \cdots + a_5(x_5 - b_5)=0$ using your equations -- you can't.  It's not possible.  That's what Dr. Lang meant.

Comment: He (Lang) can't, but you can...you are Jesus Christ after all.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas Yes, my child. I am very fond of [this song](https://youtu.be/zM6Ax8ywMds), you should be too.